# Removing rows based on column in another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Is there a way to remove rows from a dataframe, based on the column of another dataframe?

For example, Dataframe 1:

```
        Gene CHROM    POS REF ALT N_INFORMATIVE     Test       Beta       SE
AAA     1  15211   T   G          1481  1:15211 -0.0599805 0.112445
LLL     1 762061   T   A          1481 1:762061  0.2144100 0.427085
CCC     1 762109   C   T          1481 1:762109  0.2847510 0.204255
DDD     1 762273   G   A          1481 1:762273  0.0443946 0.119924
```

Dataframe 2 (only 1 column):

```
Genes
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
EEE
FFF
```

In this situtation, I want to scan Dataframe 1, column 1 for any matches to Dataframe 2, and remove matching rows.

They need to be an exact match, and the result would look like this:

```
        Gene CHROM    POS REF ALT N_INFORMATIVE     Test       Beta       SE
LLL     1 762061   T   A          1481 1:762061  0.2144100 0.427085
```

I've tried variations of this, but it hasn't worked:

```
NewDataframe <-!(Dataframe1$Gene==Dataframe2$Genes)
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Maybe use `%in%` instead of `==`. Its help page is `?\`%in%\``

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `%in%` to identify which elements from the first data frame are not contained in the second data frame, then pass the resulting logical vector to the first data frame to subset.

```
dat1 <- data.frame(id = LETTERS[1:10], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dat2 <- data.frame(id = c("B", "D"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dat1[!dat1$id %in% dat2$id, , drop = FALSE]
#    id
# 1   A
# 3   C
# 5   E
# 6   F
# 7   G
# 8   H
# 9   I
# 10  J
```